# Django-Webpack-Boilerplate: Images are not found

Tags: django, webpack, django-staticfiles, django-webpack-loader

I am using this guide https://python-webpack-boilerplate.readthedocs.io/en/latest/setup_with_django/ to setup webpack in my django app including the Tailwind extension setup. However I get the following error on the index page if I run `npm run start`:

```
ERROR in ./src/styles/index.scss (./src/styles/index.scss.webpack[javascript/auto]!=!./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ruleSet[1].rules[3].use[1]!./node_modules/postcss-loader/dist/cjs.js!./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js!./src/styles/index.scss) 5:36-100
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '/static/img/img_category/imgname.png' in 'C:\Path\to\\App\website\frontend\src\styles'
```

Could someone explain the issue to me? To me it looks like the files in the static folder, that are not generated by webpack cannot be accessed.
In my understanding I have files from the nodes_modules and my own static files and webpack helps me to get the relevant files from nodes_modules, but i should still be able to use my custom static files, no?

I am thankful for any help!